# Reducing console size

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application

I got a problem with changing console size. This is my code:

```
BOOL setConsole(int x, int y)
{
hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE); 
hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE); 
if (hStdin == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || 
    hStdout == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
{
    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("GetStdHandle"),
        TEXT("Console Error"), MB_OK);
    return false;
}


SMALL_RECT windowSize = {0, 0, x-1, y-1};

// Change the console window size:
SetConsoleWindowInfo(hStdout, TRUE, &windowSize);

COORD c = { x, y};

//Change the internal buffer size:
SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hStdout, c);


SetConsoleDisplayMode(hStdout,CONSOLE_FULLSCREEN_MODE, &c);

return true;
}
```

It works perfectly fine, when I try to enlarge the console. When one parameter is smaller than previous one nothing happens. What is wrong?

@edit: after some tests I noticed, that resizing(reducing) is possible if I change one parameter at once. Example(assume console is 100x100)

```
 setConsole(90,90); //dosen't work.
 setConsole(90,100);
 setConsole(90,90); // works perfectly
```

WHY?!

Comment: TIP : check if those operations fail and if so check GetLastError() for errorcode.

Comment: Everything works just fine, no errors come up.

Comment: Hmm, this is the wrong way around.  You can't make it bigger.  The window can't be larger than the buffer, it will fail with error 87.

Comment: Did you check your coordinates with GetLargestConsoleWindowSize?

Answer (score 7):

`SetConsoleScreenBufferSize` changes the size of the internal buffer of the console.
Changing it has no effect on the console windows extent.
Call `SetConsoleWindowInfo` if you need an effect on the visible part of the console (buffer).

The window buffer cannot be smaller than the internal buffer , and decreasing it will also decrease the internal buffer, 
but not the other way around.

If you call `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize` with illegal value in COORDS (e.g. too little height/width) then you get an
error, usually `87 'invalid argument'.`

Try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> 

using namespace std;


void SetWindow(int Width, int Height) 
{ 
    _COORD coord; 
    coord.X = Width; 
    coord.Y = Height; 

    _SMALL_RECT Rect; 
    Rect.Top = 0; 
    Rect.Left = 0; 
    Rect.Bottom = Height - 1; 
    Rect.Right = Width - 1; 

    HANDLE Handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);      // Get Handle 
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(Handle, coord);            // Set Buffer Size 
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(Handle, TRUE, &Rect);            // Set Window Size 
} 

int main(void) 
{     
    SetWindow(80,40);
    int dx=1,i=5,l=0;

     while(l<5)
     {
        i=i+dx;
        if( (i<1) || (i>10)){ dx=-dx; l++;}

        SetWindow(10*i,5*i);
        Sleep(100);

     }

  cout<<" \nPress any key to continue\n";
  cin.ignore();
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or you could just call `SetConsoleWindowInfo` *before* `SetConsoleScreenBufferSize`.

Comment: In using your `SetWindow()` function I am getting the error that `STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE` is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party ...

As far as can be devised from MSDN and a few tests, the screen buffer can't be set smaller than the window's extent or the window's extent made bigger than the screen buffer.

One hack is to shrink the window to a minimal before changing the buffer size :

```
static void
set_console_size(HANDLE screen_buffer, SHORT width, SHORT height)
{
    assert(screen_buffer != NULL);
    assert(width > 0);
    assert(height > 0);

    COORD const size = { width, height };
    BOOL success;

    SMALL_RECT const minimal_window = { 0, 0, 1, 1 };
    success = SetConsoleWindowInfo(screen_buffer, TRUE, &minimal_window);
    CHECK(success);

    success = SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(screen_buffer, size);
    CHECK(success);

    SMALL_RECT const window = { 0, 0, size.X - 1, size.Y - 1 };
    success = SetConsoleWindowInfo(screen_buffer, TRUE, &window);
    CHECK(success);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
system("mode 650");
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code provided by 'Software_Designer' on Oct 15' 12 and created a command line utility to set the console size and scroll buffers.

I compiled it using DEV C++ (http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html).

An executable is included in https://sourceforge.net/projects/wa2l-wintools/. I hope this helps.

```
/*
 * consolesize.cpp - set console size and buffer dimensions
 *
 * [00] 02.07.2016 CWa  Initial Version
 *
 * inspired by: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900713/reducing-console-size
 *
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h> 

using namespace std;


// SetWindow(Width,Height,WidthBuffer,HeightBuffer) -- set console size and buffer dimensions
//
void SetWindow(int Width, int Height, int WidthBuffer, int HeightBuffer) { 
    _COORD coord; 
    coord.X = WidthBuffer; 
    coord.Y = HeightBuffer; 

    _SMALL_RECT Rect; 
    Rect.Top = 0; 
    Rect.Left = 0; 
    Rect.Bottom = Height - 1; 
    Rect.Right = Width - 1; 

    HANDLE Handle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);      // Get Handle 
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(Handle, coord);            // Set Buffer Size 
    SetConsoleWindowInfo(Handle, TRUE, &Rect);            // Set Window Size 
}  // SetWindow



// main(Width,Height,WidthBuffer,HeightBuffer) -- main
//
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {     
    int width = 80;
    int height = 25;
    int wbuffer = width + 200;
    int hbuffer = height + 1000;

    if ( argc == 5 ){
        width = atoi(argv[1]);
        height = atoi(argv[2]);
        wbuffer = atoi(argv[3]);
        hbuffer = atoi(argv[4]);
    } else if ( argc > 1 ) {
        cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " [ width height bufferwidth bufferheight ]" << endl << endl;
        cout << "  Where" << endl;
        cout << "    width            console width" << endl;
        cout << "    height           console height" << endl;
        cout << "    bufferwidth      scroll buffer width" << endl;
        cout << "    bufferheight     scroll buffer height" << endl;
        return 4;
    }    

    SetWindow(width,height,wbuffer,hbuffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally cracked the code on this after a dedicated day of research or so.  Discovered some things that aren't in the MS documentation.  Lots of us know that calls to SetConsoleWindowInfo() will fail if the console window buffer isn't large enough, but there's more.   [Please see my answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69349833/setconsolewindowinfo-function-keeps-returning-false/76196850#76196850)