# How to set no-wrap at Clion's screen buffer size

Tags: c, windows, terminal, clion

I have written a c program for making a function appear as a graph on terminal (Windows cmd).
While I can configure the buffer screen size as shown in 1st picture to show a result inside a two dimensional array (160 characters wide), I cannot achieve the same for Clion because Clion wraps the results. Where is the same configuration for clion?

Terminal (cmd) result after configuring the screen buffer size width to 160:
[image]

Clion result:
[image]

Comment: Please add windows tag. WinAPI has functions to manipulate window size.

Comment: @ЯрославМашко, I am not sure for what do you mean exactly and why is this important, but I 've added a windows tag, if you meant this.

Comment: Clarification: you're asking how to set the size of the terminal window that's hosted in CLion?

Comment: Never used a Clion myself. Using linux these times. What I've used in Windows, Visual Studio era, is, changing screen size app layer. Google SetConsoleScreenBufferSize.

Comment: @ЯрославМашко, thanks for your suggestion, I've already searched with similar keywords at no avail.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe, well, clion has a terminal window that needs to accept as a result an Array 160 wide without wrapping it as you can see in the 2nd picture. Windows cmd has a option as I show in 1st picture, but I cannot find the same for clion. I 've edited the question accordingly. Thanks

Comment: @YannisDran Quick search on SO suggests : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12900713/reducing-console-size. Question title says that there are some problems with shrinking console window. But there are code to enlarge console, and it works, presumably.

Comment: Pls, see my answer in 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52268686/how-can-i-expand-the-max-width-of-the-run-tool-window-in-clion-intellij/