# SetConsoleWindowInfo function keeps returning false

Tags: c++, console-application

I am trying to make myself a lightweight console graphic engine as a part of trying to learn the language and I came across this error while trying to resize the console window. Here is my code.

```
    Sc_Buffer = new CHAR_INFO[Sc_Width * Sc_Height];

    _ConsoleOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    if (_ConsoleOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Invalid Output Handle."), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
        return FALSE;
    }
    else if (!SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(_ConsoleOut))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Unable to Initialize screen buffer."), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
        return FALSE;
    }
    else if (!SetConsoleWindowInfo(_ConsoleOut, TRUE, &Sc_Range))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Unable to set screen resolution."), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);
        return FALSE;
    }
```

The last "if" statement for resizing the console keeps returning false and I can't seem to find a reason for it.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Best regards!

Comment: _"...If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, __call GetLastError__...."_  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolewindowinfo and make the call (to `GetLastError`) the instant you have tested the result - almost any other call or library function can/will overwrite the error code.

Comment: It looks like that method may fail because the [new windows terminal hasn't currently implemented the virtual terminal sequences to handle this.](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5094) Apparently these older methods now just emit the virtual terminal sequences if I'm reading the documentation correctly. That said... still check `GetLastError`

Comment: I changed the size of the window to be the same size as the screen buffer and it worked but I don't understand the problem there. and I ran the GetLastError function and I got 87 as the return value.

Answer (score 1):

1.) SetConsoleWindowInfo() has issues.  It can only successfully resize a window rectangle when it's CLEARLY increasing or decreasing in size. Hence, a 40x50 rectangle that is increasing to 38x70 isn't really a CLEAR fact of increase to this API because of the 38 value being smaller than 40.   You might think that total area of the rectangle might be a determining factor, but testing has shown that it is not, oddly enough.

The solution is to set intermediate rectangle COORDs which are a clear increase/decrease to the API ... and then perform a 2nd call for the final desired rectangle value.  I'll give you a function I hacked together for this.

2.) Another thing to know is that when resizing a console window rectangle, you must also care for the console window buffer.  Like it sounds, the buffer is memory space for console window data.  It must ALWAYS be equal to or larger than the target window rectangle.

Therefore, if you are INCREASING the window rectangle you must first increase the console window buffer with a call to SetConsoleScreenBufferSize() -- assuming the current buffer is smaller than the target console window rectangle.  If you try to set the console window rectangle larger than the current console window buffer, SetConsoleWindowInfo() will surely fail.  But if the current console window buffer is already large enough to accommodate the larger target window rectangle, then the call to SetConsoleScreenBufferSize() is not required.  Simple enough, right?  So, after you have cared for the console window buffer, then you would call  SetConsoleWindowInfo() to set the console window rectangle to the target size.

If you are SHRINKING the console window rectangle, then the current buffer size would never be an issue -- except for aesthetics... eg: scroll bars appear on bottom and side when the buffer is larger than the console window rectangle.  To make those disappear, you would first call SetConsoleWindowInfo() to set the console window rectangle smaller -- and THEN you would call SetConsoleScreenBufferSize() to shrink the console window buffer, making the scroll bars vanish.   Note that this is the reverse order of the INCREASING method.

Here is get_intermediate_coords()

```
/*------------------------------------------------------------------------

get_intermediate_coords()

SetConsoleWindowInfo() has issues.  It can only successfully resize a 
window rectangle when it's CLEARLY increasing or decreasing in size. Hence, 
a 40x50 rectangle that is increasing to 38x70 isn't really a CLEAR fact of
increase to this API because of the 38 value being smaller than 40.  You might
think that total area of the rectangle might be a determining factor, but 
testing has shown that it is not, oddly enough.

The solution is to set intermediate rectangle COORDs which are a clear 
increase/decrease to the API .. and then perform a 2nd call for the final desired 
rectangle value, like this:

Current: 40x50 
Interm:  37x48 <-- clearly smaller than Current.
Final:   38x70 <-- Clearly larger than Intermediate

PARAMS: 
    COORD cur -- current window wdth and hgt 
    COORD targ -- target window wdth and hgt
    BOOL shrink_ok -- it's OK to provide a lower intermediate value than current 
    and target COORDs.  Else larger COORDs than current and target will be given.

RETURNS:  COORD structure having intermediate wdth and hgt COORDs

*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
COORD get_intermediate_coords(COORD cur, COORD targ, BOOL shrink_ok)
{
COORD interm;

if(shrink_ok)
{
    interm.X = min(cur.X, targ.X) - 1;
    interm.Y = min(cur.Y, targ.Y) - 1;
}
else
{
    interm.X = max(cur.X, targ.X) + 1;
    interm.Y = max(cur.Y, targ.Y) + 1;
}

return interm;
}
```